# как вставить "-"в логическое выражение?

Tags: python

Хочу чтобы выдал значение *-True*(в одной строке), но вместо этого в итоге выдаёт False.

В чём дело?

Версия пайтона, актуальная.

[image: вывод]

```
name = 'Renat'
print('-You\'r name is Renat')
print('-' + name == 'Renat')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в приоритете операций. Операция конкатенации (`+`) выше приоритетом, чем операция сравнения (`==`). Чтобы выводило так, как это хотите вы, нужно вручную обозначить порядок операций (и не забыть про приведение к строке):

```py
name = 'Renat'
print('-You\'r name is Renat')
print('-' + str(name == 'Renat'))
```

Answer (score 2):

можно использовать f-строки

```
print(f"-{name == 'Renat'}")
```

Comment: мне этот вариант нравится больше т.к. не надо явно преобразовывать `bool` в строку)